# Trying to scrape one element nested within a tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to capture only the "**Other**" text, essentially extracting the strong tag elements

```html
<ul class="listing-row__meta">
                        <li>
                            <strong>Ext. Color:</strong>

                                Other
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

My code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer

response = requests.get('https://www.cars.com/for-sale/searchresults.action/?mdId=21811&mkId=20024&page=1&perPage=100&rd=99999&searchSource=PAGINATION&showMore=false&sort=relevance&stkTypId=28880&zc=11209')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

posts = soup.find_all(class_='shop-srp-listings__inner')

with open('posts.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = writer(csv_file)
    headers = ['title', 'color', 'price']
    csv_writer.writerow(headers)

    for post in posts:
        title = post.find(class_="listing-row__title").get_text().replace('\n', '').strip()
        color = post.find("li").get_text().replace('\n', '').strip()
        colorremove = color.strong.extract()
        price = post.find("span", attrs={"class": "listing-row__price"}).get_text().replace('\n', '').strip()
        csv_writer.writerow([title, colorremove, price])
```

This particular script doesn't run, prior to this I had just kept the color line and that works fine, but it pics up the "Ext. Color"

Answer (score 1):

You can `find` the `<strong>` element and then get its [`next_sibling`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

markup = r"""
<ul class="listing-row__meta">
                        <li>
                            <strong>Ext. Color:</strong>

                                Other
                        </li>
                    </ul>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, "html.parser")
print(soup.find("strong").next_sibling.strip())
```

Result:

```
Other
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use stripped_strings on parent class

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<ul class="listing-row__meta">
                        <li>
                            <strong>Ext. Color:</strong>

                                Other
                        </li>
                    </ul>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
firstItem = soup.select_one('.listing-row__meta')
strings = [string for string in firstItem.stripped_strings]
print(strings[1])
```